# The relationship between linear recursion, binary recursion and runtime

Tags: algorithm, recursion, runtime

Say we have a method that takes n steps, but that calls itself linearly at the worst case n times. In such a case would the Big O would be n*n? So is a recursive call generally n^2 similarly to two for loops?

Let's now take a binary recursion algorithm such as binary Fibonacci. 1 call of that algorithm takes n step, but let's say it can reiterate up to n times. Would the run-time of that algorithm be 2^n?

Comment: This probably belongs on: http://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead of here. You'll get better answers in a community devoted to that sort of thing.

Comment: @ArtB Are you sure? There's a lot of runtime analysis questions on [so], and, from what I've seen, the questions on [cs.se] are a bit more ... shall we say ... difficult, or complex.

Answer (score 1):

Let `f()` be a function which calls itself n times. Consider the C code representing the function `f()`.

```
int f(int n)
{
  int i;
  if(n==0)
  {
     printf("\n Recursion Stopped");
  }
  else
  {
     for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
     {
        printf("\n Hello");
     }  
     f(n-1);
  }
}
```

For `n = 5`, the message `Hello` will be printed `15` times.
For `n = 10`, the message `Hello` will be printed `55` times.

In general the message will be printed `n*(n+1)/2` times.

Thus the complexity of the function **f()** is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**. Remember `f()` is a function which has a complexity `n` and `f()` is recursively called `n` times. The complexity of such a function is equal to the following loop order if the inner loop contains constant time expressions like addition, subtraction etc.

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
  for(j=i;j<=n;j++)
  {
     /* Some constant time operation */
  }
}
```

For a `Binary Recursion` the time complexity is **O(2<sup>n</sup>)**.

A Binary Recursive function calls itself twice.

The following function `g()` is an example for binary recursion, (which is a `Fibonacci binary recursion`)

```
int g(int n)
{
  int i;
  if(n==0)
  {
     printf("\n Recursion Stopped");
  }
  else
  {
     printf("\n Hello");
     g(n-1);
     g(n-2);
  }
}
```

The recurrence relation is `g(n) = g(n-1)+g(n-2)`,  for `n>1`.

Solving which we get an upper bound of **O(2<sup>n</sup>)**. 
The function `g()` is also **Θ(φ<sup>n</sup>)**,
where `φ` is the `golden ratio` and **φ = ((1+ √5)/2)**